# What might be the licence for OpenAI model generated code snippets?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, multi-licensing

I saw an interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZSFNUT6iY8) on computer-generated code snippets. The model has been trained on thousands of open source GitHub repositories.

In the video, an AI model produced some small code snippets.  Given an input, for example, a function name with a comment, the model wrote correct implementation code of the function. I assume the AI model was trained on repositories with different open sources licences. I also assume this model will be useful if added to developer productivity tools.

What might be the licences for the code that was generated by such a tool?

Comment: You'll need to go to court to find out, and the answer is *extremely* country specific. A related question is the legal responsibility of autonomous vehicles (or cruise missiles). A related project is https://www.decoder-project.eu/ (currently offline for maintenance)

Comment: Not posting an answer, but as far as I know it's quite a contraversial topic too, Creative Commons also have a take on it. "For a work to be protected by copyright, there needs to be creative involvement on the part of an “author.”" "Nevertheless, some countries (e.g. United Kingdom, Ireland, and New Zealand) do grant copyright-like protection to computer-generated works." "AI needs to be properly explored and understood before copyright or any intellectual property issues can be seriously considered." https://creativecommons.org/2020/08/10/no-copyright-protection-for-ai-generated-output/

Comment: Repeating my comment from question 10289: This is a very interesting question, and difficult to answer. There has been an article on this by WIPO wipo.int/wipo_magazine/en/2017/05/article_0003.html which I found interesting to read. But it does not give a definite answer, as IP law has not anticipated this case. The answer might be country-specific, which many of us will find frustrating to deal with.